# istream operator >> not recognising '\n' character

Tags: c++, char, ifstream, istream, peek

I am basically reading a `.txt` file and storing values.

For example:

```
Student- Mark
Tennis
```

It will store `Mark` into memory as the `studentName`.

Now...If it is just

```
Student-
Tennis
```

Then it will work fine and produce an error.

However, if the file looks like this

```
Student-(space)(nothing here)
Tennis
```

It will store `Tennis` into memory as the `studentName`, when if fact it should store nothing and produce an error. I use `'\n'` character to determine if there is anything after the `-` character. This is my code...

```
istream& operator>> (istream& is, Student& student)
{   
    is.get(buffer,200,'-');
    is.get(ch);
    if(is.peek() == '\n')
    {
        cout << "Nothing there" << endl;
    }
    is >> ws;
    is.getline(student.studentName, 75);
}
```

I think it is because the `is.peek()` is recognizing white space, but then if I try removing white space using `is >> ws`, it removes the `'\n'` character and still stores `Tennis` as the `studentName`.

Would really mean a lot if someone could help me solve this problem.

Comment: your is.peek() == `\n`.....if this is true, then you should return from the function.

Comment: use find_first_of() function to find the first space so you can recognize which spaces you should remove.

Comment: It should probably be `\n\r` to take into account carriage returns

Comment: @hagubear, what about the whitespaces? What if `is.peek()==ws` and everything after is blank? That's the trouble I am having

Comment: Since you only want to read a line, use `std::getline` to read the line in, and then parse it.

Comment: Is this an assignment? Are you permitted to use std::string?

Comment: @AtlasC1, I prefer using `c string arrays`. Isn't there a way of doing this using `c string arrays`?

Comment: @SamThers There is, but C++ strings are safer and free you from the burden of managing your own memory. When used as intended they also prevent stack smash attacks. I would strongly discourage you from using C-style strings. There is no time like the present to make a change for the better. (I'd also note that there are fewer things more frustrating on SO than someone saying "I'd prefer to use the wrong tool for the job." It results in needlessly complicated and broken answers.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore whitespace but *not* `'\n'` you can't use `std::ws` as easily: it will skip over all whitespace and aside from `' '` the characters `'\n'` (newline), `'\t'` (tab), and `'\r'` (carriage return) are considered whitespace (I think there are actually even a few more). You *could* redefine what whitespace means for your stream (by replacing the stream's `std::locale` with a custom `std::ctype<char>` facet which has changed idea of what whitespace means) but that's probably a bit more advanced (as far as I can tell, there is about a handful of people who could do that right away; ask about it and I'll answer that question if I notice it, though...). An easier approach is to simply read the tail of the line using `std::getline()` and see what's in there.

Another alternative is create your own manipulator, let's say, `skipspace`, and use that prior to checking for newline:

```
std::istream& skipspace(std::istream& in) {
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> it(in), end;
    std::find_if(it, end, [](char c){ return c != ' '; });
    return in;
}
// ...
if ((in >> skipspace).peek() != '\n') {
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to peek characters.  I would use `std::getline()` and let it handle line breaks for you, then use `std::istringstream` for parsing:

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& is, Student& student)
{   
    std::string line;
    if (!std::getline(is, line))
    {
        std::cout << "Can't read student name" << std::endl;
        return is;
    }

    std::istringstream iss(line);
    std::string ignore;
    std::getline(iss, ignore, '-');
    iss >> std::ws;
    iss.getline(student.studentName, 75);

    /*
    read and store className if needed ... 

    if (!std::getline(is, line))
    {
        std::cout << "Can't read class name" << std::endl;
        return is;
    }

    std::istringstream iss2(line);
    iss2.getline(student.className, ...);
    */

    return is;
}
```

Or, if you can change `Student::studentName` into a `std::string` instead of a `char[]`:

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& is, Student& student)
{   
    std::string line;
    if (!std::getline(is, line))
    {
        std::cout << "Can't read student name" << std::endl;
        return is;
    }

    std::istringstream iss(line);
    std::string ignore;
    std::getline(iss, ignore, '-');
    iss >> std::ws >> student.studentName;

    /*
    read and store className if needed ... 

    if (!std::getline(is, student.className))
    {
        std::cout << "Can't read class name" << std::endl;
        return is;
    }
    */

    return is;
}
```

Comment: What if I want to use `c style arrays`? I prefer using `c style arrays`, its just when `is.peek()==ws` and everything after the whitespace is blank that is the problem

Comment: I would not recommend using a C style array for the reading/parsing. The STL's parsing functionality prefer `std::string`. But, as you can see in my first example, the result of the parsing is stored in a final C Style array, at least.